# How to describe "A specific food attracts me and makes me feel hungry"?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-choice

How to describe "A specific food attracts me and makes me feel hungry" ?
As far as I know, appetite may fit this circumstance. However, I do not know how to use it. I may say "I have a strong appetite today.", but I do not know how to describe "A specific food makes me to have a strong appetite now". Verbs, phrases, or adjectives are all welcome.

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say "Craving".

The word [crave](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/crave?s=t) is used to talk about wanting food a lot.

> "I have a bad craving for pickles today."

and

> "If you crave potato chips, you may have a salt deficiency."

are both good examples of this. 
A more slangy word for "crave" is ["Hankering"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hankering?s=t) which means pretty much the exact same thing.

> "I have a hankering to eat fried chicken and salsa."

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that **appetite** is a **general** wanting of food.

In BrE, when one likes a particular food, one usually wants **more** of it.
The adjective that describes this is **moreish**:

> P1: Those cookies are very moreish
>   P2: Be careful of your waistline!

In AmE, one might say *something* is **habit forming**: the more you **have**, the more you **want**

> Reese's Peanut Butter Cups can be **habit forming**.